# removeAttribute is not a function when using angular ng-attr

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `ng-attr-data-index={{$index}}` in here:

```
<div class="entry__row" ng-repeat-n="entryRows" ng-attr-data-index={{$index}}>
...
</div>
```

Now, angular added `data-index=0` (and so on) properly, but `ng-attr-data-index={{$index}}` is still there, and I get this error from console:

```
TypeError: t.removeAttribute is not a function
```

Also, this is ng-repeat-n: https://github.com/connorbode/angular-repeat-n

Comment: The `removeAttribute()` method removes the specified attribute from an element. It is a method of `DOM` object. Also note that you did not mention how you are trying to use this _method_

Comment: Post `ng-RepeatN` source.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @RayonDabre I'm not using it. angular do. for removing plain `ng-attr-data-index={{$index}}`

Comment: @dfsq Didn't know it could be necessary. done.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Sorry. my bad!